# Changing the data on a view depending on which button was clicked in the last view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a beginner in iOS development and have started out with Objective C. I am creating a quiz application that does the following:

**edit:
When addition is clicked it goes to the QuizViewController and displays addition questions, when subtracttion is clicked it goes to the QuizViewController and displays subtraction questions etc**

(I know something similar was asked in swift but I don't know Swift)

My quiz app storyboard looks like this:

ViewController -> QuizViewController -> ResultViewController

Buttons on ViewController:

Addition

Subtraction

Multiplication

The whole view controller is connected to QuizViewController through 1 Segue called "toQuiz"

How do I pass this information?

Should I make separate view controllers after all?

Comment: Read up on MVC in iOS, then on prepareForSegue:.

Comment: Its ultimately useful for the op to know MVC, but in this case M  doesn't enter the picture as one would not store the results of the button press in a model for example, thus instructing them to read about MVC is only going to confuse them into wondering how on earth it helps them in this specific situation.  @Nima beginners use the term view when they mean view controller and vice versa, and your question is full of things that don't make sense. Do you want to display a different view on an existing view controller or display different view controllers depending on button press?

Comment: Its not clear what you actually want to do. Please clarify the question.

Comment: @Essenceofchicken Unit  My apologies, I want to display different data in the same views on a different view controller depending on which button was clicked. Thank you for the advice